# How to return object within service on AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I'm trying to populate data on my google chart with AngularJS. However not is return the object. See:

```
function drawNew($scope,conf,GetData,i) {

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var data = addData(GetData,conf);
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'+i));
        chart.draw(data, {title: "OOOPOPOP", width: 800, height: 300});
    }   
}

function addData(GetData,abelua) {
    GetData.Values(abelua)
        .then(function(msg) {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Assertivas');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Contador');
            data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'annotation'});
            data.addRows(msg.data.length);               
            angular.forEach(msg.data,function(value,key){
                data.setCell(key,0, value.ASSERTIVA);
                data.setCell(key,1, value.CONTADOR);
                data.setCell(key,2, value.CONTADOR);
            });



        });

    return data;

}
```

On My Service:

```
    function Values(conf) {
        return $http.post('php/Values.php',conf);
    }
```

On `addData` not is returning the object with data populating. What is wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use  the [Angular Google Chart directive](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/).

Comment: `var data` is wrapped in a promise callback. It hasn't run yet when you return.